# How to rename a property in an derived class?

Tags: c#, properties

These are my wishes:

```
public class Base<T> => abstract T Children {get;set;}
public class Derived<myclass> => myclass AnotherNameProp {get;set}
```

Instead of an abstract class, there can be an interface.

In VB, this problem is implemented like this:

```
myclass AnotherNameProp {het;set} As Children
```

How to do it in C#?
Thanks!

I did it on VB, but I don't know how to do it in C#

**UPD1**, especially for @jmcilhinney:

I wrote "like it", now exactly, from Microsoft:

```
Public Interface IDemo
     Sub DoSomething()
end interface
Public Class implementIDemo
     Implements IDemo
     Private Sub DoSomething() Implements IDemo.DoSomething
     end sub
end class
Dim varAsInterface As IDemo = New implementIDemo()
Dim varAsClass As implementIDemo = New implementIDemo()
```

In VB I can change Bold and that will become the name of the Sub, for example:

Private Sub **AnotherSomething()** Implements IDemo.DoSomething

I want the same in c#

Comment: You can't rename a property. But you can write `AnotherNameProp { get => Children; set => Children = value; }`

Comment: I don't know what universe you live in but, in this universe, that's not valid VB.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman
Yes, but this is a doubling of properties. I have considered this idea before. It would be possible to declare Children private and use your method in a derived class. But interfaces don't allow private ones. Thanks.